# How to Translate this statement in MS Access Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

SELECT ALL Duplicate Document No. FROM Document No. COLUMN IF AND ONLY IF it has a Duplicate Entries IN Distribution COLUMN.

Say:

```
Document No
111
123
121
111
111

Distribution
AAA
BBB
AAA
ABC
AAA
```

Result

```
111 AAA
111 AAA
```

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: Do you need the duplicates? Would a row count do fine instead?

Comment: @ Rams, its just in MS Access

Comment: @jarlh, I need a result such as this Result 111 AAA 111 AAA

Comment: I dont know how to format it in table, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get all the duplicate records by using `group by` and `having clause`

```
select * from table where (Document_No,Distribution ) in (
select Document_No,Distribution  from table 
group by Document_No,Distribution having count(*) >1
)
```

or

```
select t1.Document_No,t1.Distribution from table t1 join 
(select Document_No,Distribution  from table 
group by Document_No,Distribution having count(*) >1
) as t2 on t1.Document_No=t2.Document_No and t1.Distribution=t2.Distribution
```

Comment: @Daryll comments aren't intended for chit-chat. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), it specifically says you should not post thank you notes.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Saying thank you is better than earning e-badges which is auto-performed by a machine

Comment: @Daryll please behave according to the site rules. If you believe those are incorrect, you can take it up on the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). The link I provided specifically states not to thank, and is an official help document for this site. In a previous [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/7296893), it was decided that thank-you comments should not be posted, and if they are, they should be flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT
    [Document No]
    Distribution
FROM your_table
GROUP BY [Document No], Distribution
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    [Document No],
    Distribution
FROM Document
GROUP BY [Document No], Distribution
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```